# Best Practices for deploying to multiple databases in Web 8.5

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, web8.5, broker, upgrade

Background: I'm working on a project where we are upgrading from Tridion 2013 to Web 8.5. We currently have several sites set up in the existing Tridion 2013 implementation that connect to several different Content Delivery databases. The Deployer is configured to send Content to these various different databases, depending on certain conditions about where things are located in the CMS.

This all works fine for Tridion 2013, as each web application either connects directly to one of these Content Delivery databases or it incorporates Content published to a file system. In Web 8.5, however, it's not clear how we can configure our web applications to connect to the appropriate Content Delivery database. We should be able to configure the Web 8.5 Deployer to send content to several different databases, similar to the current Tridion 2013 setup. However, how can our web apps know which Content Delivery database contains the Content it consumes, considering our CD environment has one single Discovery Service entry point? Is there some routing logic handled by the Discovery Service? Or do we need multiple Discovery Services (i.e. one for each Content Delivery database)?

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part of your question is where you say you have a single CD environment with a single discovery endpoint. This arrangement doesn't fit well with the rest of the situation you describe. Generally for a given broker database, you'll want a matching CD environment with it's own discovery endpoint. Then to consume the content, it's simply a case of asking the correct discovery service.

Comment: If that is true, I don't see why CD allows us to define custom ItemTypes in the cd_storage_conf, because that allows for configuring publishing to multiple broker databases. I'm seeing an issue now where I'm able to publish to multiple broker databases, but when I try to query for the content through the Content Service, only content published to the default storage is returned.

Comment: Good point. So if you are basing it on different publications, in principle, it should work, but you'll need to have the mappings correct in topology manager in order to identify the correct publication.

Comment: Yes, this is what I would have expected. But what I am seeing is that only the default storage in the storage conf is able to be queried against via the Content Service. I've checked my publication mappings. Perhaps I should open a ticket with SDL...

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the Content Service's cd_storage_conf.xml, where we map publication IDs to storage IDs. I had overlooked this. I will update once I give it a try.

Comment: This shouldn't have changed much since 2013.

Comment: OK, so is it possible to query content published to multiple broker databases through the Content service? I was attempting to do this with some /client/v2/content.svc URLs, but they would only ever pick up content published to the DEFAULT broker database...